# AccessControl Exception while dynamically downloading .class

Tags: java, rmi

I want to dynamically download class; and below i wrote code for the same.

```
public class ClientProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {

    String serverName = "localhost";
    int port = Integer.parseInt("3000");
    SerialObj so = null;

    SecurityManager securityManager = null;
    securityManager = System.getSecurityManager();

    if(securityManager == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    RMIClassLoader.loadClass("http://localhost:80", "SerialObj.class");
          try
          {  
             Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

             so = (SerialObj) ois.readObject();
             System.out.println("read object is : " + so.getId() + ", " + so.getName());  
             client.close();
          } catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }    
}
```

Basically i try to get the class using RMIClassLoader, classes are in a location in http server, which is quite accessible.

The following are the security permissions i have granted:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

When i run this program, i get the following exception (not showing the full stack).

```
access: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:80" "connect,resolve")
```

And this also in the stack output:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:80" "connect,resolve")
```

I tried number of trial to past this, didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `java.security.policy` file if you're going to install a `SecurityManager.` Otherwise you won't be able to do anything. See the Oracle RMI Tutorial.

Comment: I have already defined policy file, not sure if permission specified therein are sufficient?

Comment: You've *written* one, but nowhere have you defined where it is to the JVM.